# Chartjs X axis labels will not display

Tags: javascript, time, chart.js

The documentation for time in ChartJs is extremely vague and gives little working examples so I'm struggling to get a time series working for temperature data recorded at a particular time. I can get the correct time format to appear in the tooltip, but it will not appear on the X axis.

Graph code:

```
<script>
            var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
            var data = {
                labels: [],
                datasets: [{
                    label: "Temperature Graph",
                    fill: false,
                    borderColor: '#3cba9f',
                    data: []
                }]
            }
            const options = {
                type: 'line',
                data: data,
                options: {
                    fill: false,
                    responsive: true,
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            type: 'time',
                            time: {
                                unit: 'day',
                                stepSize: 1,
                                displayFormats: {
                                    day: 'MMM D'
                                }

                            },
                            display: true,
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: "Date",
                            }
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true,
                            },
                            display: true,
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: "Temperature",
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }
        var chart = new Chart(ctx, options)
        </script>
```

Data collection code:

```
window.onload = function load() {
    getData();
}

var prevData = [];
var prevLabels = [];

function getData() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', encodeURI('http://localhostlocalhost/getTemp'));
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(data);

            var label = data.timestamp * 1000;

            prevData.push(data.temperature);
            prevLabels.push(label);

            chart.data.datasets[0].data = prevData;
            chart.data.labels = prevLabels;
            chart.update();
        }
        else {
            alert(xhr.status);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();

    setTimeout(getData, 10000);
}
```

Example xhr response:

```
{temperature: 17, humidity: 38, location: "location", timestamp: 1542824305}
```

The data is plotted to the graph and all works as expected, the time just does not appear on the X axis

Comment: Can you please create fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zehLx6bt/

Comment: The issue creating the time labels dynamically in real time